# Magento - Display Catalog Price Rule discount on Shopping Cart

Tags: magento, php

When I apply a Catalog Price Rule with a percentage discount (e.g. 20%) across all products, the old price and special price show on my product list and product view pages e.g.

> Old Price: £10
>
> Special Price: £8

However on the basket page it only shows the special price, so it is not immediately obvious that there is any discount, or what that discount is.

I would like to show the original grand total and the special grand total on the basket, as well as the discount percentage.

Is this possible?

I appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: @skrilled HI, sorry. This question was somehow deleted from my account, but I've got access again now. I've not tried any code yet. I was hoping to get an idea of where to start so that it works properly with percentage and fixed amount discounts. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Listing is dependent on flat tables.

You need to run indexing so that flat tables have the effect of rules applied.

So do run indexing follow it by cleaning cache and then check.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I think you may have misinterpreted the question.  By default, Magento does not show original and special price on the cart for a catalog price rule. This requires some bespoke coding.

Comment: In your code get hold of shopping cart class instance.

Now get products in cart using getProductIds function of cart class then

loop using below code logic

?php        

$origPrice = $product->getPrice() ;
$discPrice = $product->getSpecialPrice() ;
$savings = $origPrice - $discPrice;

?>